# in_array not produced expected results

Tags: php, arrays

Some simple logic using in_array but I cannot get the expected result. I am expecting both IF statements to be true. I only get the second (TRUE_TEST2) to work.

I am going a bit loopy on this! I have var_dump'd everything and can see they are both identical strings of 11 chars. Why will one work and not the other?

Thanks

#### PHP Code

```
        $follow_topics = get_user_meta(wp_get_current_user()->ID,'user_topic_follow');

        echo '1. '; var_dump($tracked_topic_slug);
        echo '2. '; var_dump('behavioural');
        echo '3. '; var_dump($follow_topics);

        echo '<br />';

        if( in_array($tracked_topic_slug, $follow_topics)) {echo 'TRUE_TEST1';}
        if( in_array('behavioural', $follow_topics)) {echo 'TRUE_TEST2';}
```

#### HTML OUTPUT

```
    1.string 'behavioural' (length=11)

    2.string 'behavioural' (length=11)

    3. array (size=2)
      0 => string 'clinical' (length=8)
      1 => string 'behavioural' (length=11)

    TRUE_TEST2
```

Comment: Running your code, as is, I get the expected result. What I would do is compare $tracked_topic_slug to 'behavioural' to see if they are the same. Could be something that is not visible.

Comment: Are you sure `true_test2` is being ouptut by your second if statement? There's no reason it should be lower case when your string within `echo` is uppercase

Comment: HPierce - you are right, i copied from website which had lowercase by CSS - I will amend original.

Comment: Hi Kainaw - I did a var_dump of both to compare and from the HTML output you can see they are both strings 11 chars long with same spelling... Any other way to compare and find what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks really weird. Can you show us result of this:

```
var_dump('behavioural' === $tracked_topic_slug);
var_dump($tracked_topic_slug === $follow_topics[1]);
```

Comment: Then `var_dump(md5('behavioural')); var_dump(md5($tracked_topic_slug));  var_dump(md5($follow_topics[1])); `

Comment: string '1929933fb74011d6fca9ef4dbbe91320' (length=32)
string 'de925b4d37a98f906f86c52d2cf70fe2' (length=32)
string '1929933fb74011d6fca9ef4dbbe91320' (length=32)

Comment: And `function strtoentity($input) { foreach (str_split($input) as $obj) { $output .= '&#' . ord($obj) . ';'; } return $output; }` and let's compare ASCII codes.

    `var_dump(strtoentity('behavioural'));     var_dump(strtoentity($tracked_topic_slug));     var_dump(strtoentity($follow_topics[1]));`

Comment: And try `var_dump(md5(trim($tracked_topic_slug)))`

Comment: Looks like first char different... string '&#98;&#101;&#104;&#97;&#118;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#97;&#108;' (length=63)
string '&#66;&#101;&#104;&#97;&#118;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#97;&#108;' (length=63)
string '&#98;&#101;&#104;&#97;&#118;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#97;&#108;' (length=63)

Comment: Aha! Fixed. I used:    if( in_array(strtolower($tracked_topic_slug), $follow_topics)) {echo 'TRUE_TEST1';}

Comment: 66 is B (uppercase) and 98 is b (lowercase). You're welcome!

Comment: Hmm. That is really sneaky. I had some CSS that was making text lowercase. Even when copying the text it copied as lowercase. So I never spotted the difference...